# Community Promotion Ads - 2012

Tags: discussion, community-ads

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Community Promotion Ads - 2013](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1519/community-promotion-ads-2013)

For one reason or another, we missed 2H 2011. Nevermind that, though, let us commence with 1H 2012! And yes, it starts in December.

#### What in the Wide, Wide World of Sports is Going On Here?

TL;DR -- put images and links in the answers. If they get voted up enough, they will appear on the main site as community promotion ads.

#### But whyyyyyyy?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- cool apple related open source apps
- the site's twitter account
- scripts packs or power tools
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. And to click on it for great justice!

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently 6) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/932).

Comment: Is there some reason why we can't just continue running our existing set of ads? Why do we need to get votes again?

Comment: To avoid staleness, mostly. Projects go defunct. Ads campaigns get stale. Users start ignoring them and makes the site boring. Bad for everyone. Starting fresh lets us also clean the slate, as otherwise new ads wouldn't be able to stand against old ads that simply are standing around with high votes. There's always the option of putting a nice, fresh new face on old services that were previously advertised.

Comment: I wonder how an ad for IE Mac would go over... :)

Comment: @JavaAndCSharp I used IE for Mac under Panther. Still installed on my eMac. But not much point in advertising a product that's so long discontinued.

Answer (score 35):

[image: Current Ask Different bounties]
<sub>(source: [herokuapp.com](https://stack-exchange-dynamic-ads.herokuapp.com/bounty.png))</sub>

Comment: Wow, is this dynamic?

Comment: @stuffe Should be, yes. Still working some bugs out though.

Comment: I've already seen the image at least 4 times.

Comment: AWESOME!!! So cool!!!!!

Comment: Wow, this is awesome! How did you get it to be dynamic?

Comment: The [Ruby programming language](http://www.ruby-lang.org/), the [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) via [Serel](http://stackapps.com/questions/3198/serel-a-ruby-library-with-full-support-for-api-2-0), and [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com/).

Comment: Has to be hosted so they know it will stay up (and on the distributed cache). There's some potential that they would be willing to host this on their servers if they can make it distributed in some way.

Comment: @jcolebrand I'm afraid I don't entirely understand. Are you talking about SE hosting this?

Comment: If they were going to do this as an ad, yes.

Comment: But we're doing this ad. And it's working.

Comment: @KyleCronin This ad is amazing and - as I suspect your server will tell you - it's used all over the network =). (We certainly use it [over on Physics](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6388/community-promotion-ads-2015/6398#6398).) Unfortunately, the new size requirements mean it will probably break going into 2016 =(. Is it reasonable to ask for a version with the new sizes?

Comment: @KyleCronin: It looks like these ads have stopped working for some reason. There's [a thread over at meta.SE about it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/294958/dynamic-bounty-ad-is-broken) that you might want to take a look at.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Thanks for the heads up, I've pushed a fix for this issue

Answer (score 14):

[image: Follow us on Twitter]

Answer (score 4):

[image: A network file-sharing application that makes sending a file to another machine on the local network as easy as dragging-and-dropping.]

Comment: Description: NitroShare is a simple, cross-platform tool for sending files to other machines on a local network. It makes sending a file to another machine on the local network as easy as dragging-and-dropping.