# Community Promotion Ads - 2013

Tags: discussion, community-ads

As it is December 2012, we are now going to reset our Community Promotion Ads for the new year.

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- interesting apple related open source apps
- the site's twitter account
- script packs or power tools
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/1519).

Answer (score 17):

[image: Current Ask Different bounties]
<sub>(source: [herokuapp.com](https://stack-exchange-dynamic-ads.herokuapp.com/bounty.png))</sub>

Comment: Isn't this twice the required number of pixels in each direction?

Comment: @DanielLawson It's retina

Comment: It isn't correct in it's count though, there are 0 active bounties worth 150 rep at the moment, yet it displays 3.

Comment: @Emil the values are totals - currently 2 bounties active, with a total of 100 rep

Comment: Ah, I see! Smart!

Comment: How was this made exactly?

Comment: @Dynamic It's a simple Sinatra app running on Heroku that uses the Stack Exchange API to query the number of active bounties and how much they're worth, then with Imagemagick generates a PNG with those numbers on it and serves it up. Add some caching and that's pretty much it.

Comment: @KyleCronin Pretty cool idea. Is Ask Different the only SE site that has this sort of ad? I'd love to implement this on other sites.

Comment: @Dynamic Feel free to use this ad on other SE sites - the app looks at the referer to determine which site to query for bounties for. As far as implementing a similar ad yourself, the code isn't public at this time, but it's not that hard to code.

Comment: I tried stealing this, only to be automatically told it wasn't an image of imgur, so it wasn't acceptable.

Comment: @Oddthinking Post with a dummy i.stack.imgur.com image, then edit the post and swap out the image URL with http://stack-exchange-dynamic-ads.herokuapp.com/bounty.png. I just tried it here on Ask Different Meta and that loophole still works.

Comment: @Kyle: I've used that trick, thanks. Does this ad actually appear in rotation on the Apple site?

Comment: @Oddthinking Yes, or at least it did until the new Community Promotion Ads thread was started.

Comment: For future readers, [here](https://github.com/kylecronin/Stack-Exchange-Bounty-Ad) is the Github repo.

Answer (score 8):

[image: Follow us on Twitter]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting.

Answer (score 8):

[image: WriteLaTeX on your iPad - Free Real Time Collaboration in Safari]

Comment: This is an ad from TeX SX, which may also be useful here - writeLaTeX is one of the few LaTeX options for scientific writing on an iPad - all done through Safari with nothing to install. Happy to let the community vote decide - I'm one of the developers of writeLaTeX, so any feedback appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the clear adherence to the site promotion policy. We don't get many questions on TeX, but it's nice to have more items here to vote on.

Comment: Also - since this works on iOS - it seems worth an up vote to me.

Answer (score -3):

[image: Backblaze Online Backup]

Answer (score -4):

[image: A network file-sharing application that makes sending a file to another machine on the local network as easy as dragging-and-dropping.]