# How does the Active Bounties Banner work?

Tags: discussion

In my Stack Exchange experience, it's the first time I'm seeing this:

[image: current bounties]

How does it work? Is there a minimum bounties value that triggers the banner? If it were to be suggested in other SE sites, how would one refer to this? Is there any other known site using it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kyle's comment on the post linked in the other answer points you in the right direction. But in case you want to jump right to it; [Community Promotion Ads - 2013](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1519/community-promotion-ads-2013/1521#comment3199_1521)

If you wanna see some serious magic, go embed https://i.stack.imgur.com/FoT1K.png on one of the other sites you listed. (e.g. create a question or an answer with the contents `![](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FoT1K.png)`

Comment: [Done!](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3706/a-dynamic-community-promotion-ad) Unfortunately, it doesn't work on IE6 :( . . . [/justkidding] :)

Answer (score 6):

It was written by a couple of our Mods I believe, and you can see how it enters the site as a normal site promoted ad:

https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1521/5472

It may not be suitable for all sites, as it doesn't scale well for the 3 figure bounty totals that some sites have, but as long as that limitation is fine, you could try it on other sites with about three lines of markdown.

Comment: Oh, I was thinking of smaller sites like WordPress/Photography/Ubuntu. Plz, gimme teh codez... no, I mean, please, you other couple of Mods, could you publish this at [Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com/)? :)

Comment: @brasofilo I've linked to the promotion showing how the image gets generated by a heroku hosted app that calls the stack API. I don't think the code behind the app is released although it may work for any site without code changes.